# How to make an error list from xml cppcheck python?

Tags: python-2.7

```
os.system("cppcheck --xml-version=2 --enable=all C:/Users/User/Desktop/el.cpp > C:/Users/User/Desktop/cppcheck-result.xml")
cppcheckxml_list = []

with open("C:/Users/User/Desktop/cppcheck-result.xml") as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        cppcheckxml_list.append(line)
```

Comment: I fixed your code block, but your question isn't clear. Please [edit] it and explain what you're trying to do, and how this code failed to do it.